# splitting .net core webapp into back end and front end on different OS

Tags: asp.net-core, operating-system, frontend, backend, centos8

I have a .net core 3.1 with razor page webapp solution that consists of multiple .net core projects, some are API. It uses identityserver4 for authentification. It can run on Centos 8 as well as on Windows 10 successfully. However, now i would like to split the front end and backend deployment.

backend to run in linux and front end to run on windows. What is the guideline to split the current webapp ?

Comment: `backend to run in linux and front end to run on windows. What is the guideline to split the current webapp` Would you like to know how to setup hosting server and host .net core app on linux and windows? Or want to determine which app is backend, which is frontend? Please clarify more about the question, so that we can understand it better.

Comment: i am doing webapp entirely in .net core 3.1 web app. i want  the backend to run on centos 8, and the front end to be on windows. i find that if i run it on linux and run it (it is running on kestrel), on windows client that is on the same network, i can also access the same webapp. so may be my question is wrong, it seems i don't need to do anything specific to split the backend and frontend? i just host and run it on linux and let user access it via windows or linux web browser. am i getting this right?

Comment: `it seems i don't need to do anything specific to split the backend and frontend? i just host and run it on linux and let user access it via windows or linux web browser. am i getting this right?` If you just want to let users access your site(s) using windows or linux web browser, hosting them on same web server is ok.

Comment: yes, @FeiHan i also do this and it is working as intended. only thing i haven't ascertained if this is the correct way. for example, am i suppose to let multiple people access it? so far it is working